# Xml based file Implementation

Tags: c#, xml

I have a big project. I make a simulation app for national exam in C#. We must have simulation file to use the application. The simulation file contains simulation title, answer key, path to question file (pdf), etc. The simulation file is also an XML based file.
My questions are:
1. What is the best implementation for read and write (also to change the title, etc) to this simulation file?
2. Do I need to separate the SimulationFileReader and SimulationFileWriter class? Or only one class contains all the read and write operation?
3. What should the class implements?

Thank you.

Comment: Hello, welcome!  I recommend you read up on the [XMLSerializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer?view=netframework-4.8) class.  If you do it right, you don't need to implement any methods to handle the serializing - just implement the class structure that will work for you, and the XMLSerializer can read and write the XML for you.  Focus on the class structure that best fits your application first, _then_ worry about serializing/deserializing.

Comment: Why do you do not use JSON instead of XML?

Comment: There a lots of different Xml libraries that you can use in Net and the BEST depends on a lot of factors.  I use most of them.  The simplest is to use the DataSet WriteXml/ReadXml.  I would create a DataTable with following columns for each test 1) Test Number 2) Question 3) Correct Answer 4) Additional Columns for each Multiple choice question. Both DataSet and DataTable have a WriteXml Method.  To use the DataTable you need to give the table a name.  I would first create the DataTable and fill in the data.  Then write to a file to see the correct format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use System.Xml.Serialization for that.
You create a regular C# class and decorate it with XML style attributes. There is an attribute for every XML type like XmlRoot, XmlArray, XmlAttribute etc.

Here is an example

```
public class CreditNote
{
    [XmlArray("items")]
    [XmlArrayItem("article")]
    public List<Article> Articles { get; } = new List<Article>();

    [XmlAttribute("reason")]
    public string Reason { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("article")]
public class Article
{
    [XmlAttribute("itemNo")]
    public string ItemNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Then you turn an XML file into an instance with XmlSerializer.Serialize and instance into file with XmlSerializer.Deserialize.

```
T serializeObject<T>(string file)
{
    T obj = default;

    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open))
    {
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            obj = (T)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(sr);
            sr.Close();
        }
        fs.Close();
    }

    return obj;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable("Test_1");
            dt.Columns.Add("Number", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Question", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Answer", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("A", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("B", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("C", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("D", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("E", typeof(string));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, "Red Fruit", "A", "Apple", "Banana", "Grape", "Orange", "Pear" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, "How much is 1 + 2", "C", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" });

            dt.WriteXml(FILENAME);
        }
    }
}
```